# stop main thread while getting response from server

Tags: android

```
  UIHelper.showProgressDialog(this);
  ValCircuitPriceController controller = new ValCircuitPriceController(PlaceOrderActivity.this, this.exchangeID, this.instrumentID, et_PriceValue.getText().toString());
  controller.start();

  if (isValCircuitPrice) {
      order.setOrderPrice(
          Double.parseDouble(et_PriceValue.getText().toString()));
      isValCircuitPrice = false;
  } else {
      break;
  }
```

This is my code i am calling Controller to get response from server but before getting response from server my if condition calls and isValCircuitPrice is by default false after getting response i will make it true

Comment: Please add error log.
Before that are you doing network operation in main thread?

Answer (score 0):

User AsynTask for done this

```
private class ValCircuitPriceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         ValCircuitPriceController controller = new 
         ValCircuitPriceController(PlaceOrderActivity.this, this.exchangeID, 
         this.instrumentID, et_PriceValue.getText().toString());
         controller.start();

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (isValCircuitPrice) {
            order.setOrderPrice(
            Double.parseDouble(et_PriceValue.getText().toString()));
            isValCircuitPrice = false;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        UIHelper.showProgressDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Finally execute your asyntask

```
new ValCircuitPriceTask ().execute("");
```

Comment: its no working i m writing all code in AsyncTask but for executing AsyncTask my if loop execute

Comment: I stop the main thread 2 sec but still my if condition execute before asynctask

Comment: I also use AsyncTask get() but i cant get solution

Comment: could you finally get solution?

Comment: send me all exact code on my Skype or email - gautam90055@gmail.com